# Double explode a text field containing date and time in PHP

Tags: php

I have a lengthy text field containing multiple date and time separated by comma. Following is the example

```
2013-08-26 10:00:00,2013-08-26 15:00:00,2013-08-26 20:00:00
2013-08-27 01:00:00,2013-08-27 06:00:00,2013-08-27 11:00:00
2013-08-27 16:00:00,2013-08-27 21:00:00,2013-08-28 02:00:00
2013-08-28 07:00:00,2013-08-28 12:00:00,2013-08-28 17:00:00
```

From the above example I need the following structure

Step 1: Split comma separated values into one array.
Step 2: From the above obtained array push all 2013-08-26 dates to one array, the 2013-08-27 to another array and then 2013-08-28.

I successfully exploded the main text to one array but did not succeed to obtain list of values of one particular date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (explode(PHP_EOL, $dates) as $line)
{
    foreach (explode(',', $line) as $dt)
    {
        $dateVal = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dt));

        switch ($dateVal)
        {
            case '2013-08-26':
                $arr1[] = $dt;
                break;
            case '2013-08-27':
                $arr2[] = $dt;
                break;
            case '2013-08-28':
                $arr3[] = $dt;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

[**Online demo**](https://eval.in/120826)

Answer (score 0):

```
$dates = "2013-08-26 10:00:00,2013-08-26 15:00:00,2013-08-26 20:00:00
2013-08-27 01:00:00,2013-08-27 06:00:00,2013-08-27 11:00:00
2013-08-27 16:00:00,2013-08-27 21:00:00,2013-08-28 02:00:00
2013-08-28 07:00:00,2013-08-28 12:00:00,2013-08-28 17:00:00";

$dates = explode("\n", $dates);

foreach($dates as $date) {
   $date = explode(",", $date);
   var_dump($date); 
   // i.e. with $date[1] I will get the middle date of particular line.
}
```

`$date` inside foreach, as you can see becomes an array (after exploding) containing all dates separated by commas in one line.

Answer (score 0):

it's been a while since the last time I used PHP, but this is my rusty solution:

```
$map = array();
$records = explode(',', $input);
foreach( $records as $record )
{
    $a = explode(" ", $record);

    if(!array_key_exists( $a[0], $map ))
        $map[$a[0]] = array();

    $map[$a[0]][] = $a[1];
}
var_dump($map);
```

I haven't tested it, sorry. But it might work...

it should give you something like:

```
array(2)
(
    ['2014-03-14'] => array(2)
    (
        [0] => '04:03:24'
        [1] => '04:03:25'
    ) 
    ['2014-03-14'] => array(2)
    (
        [0] => '04:03:24'
        [1] => '04:03:25'
    ) 
)
```